# Which Java package should I use: OpenJDK or Oracle JDK?

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I'm new to Java development under Ubuntu. When I typed javac in the terminal, it prompted me to install OpenJDK and a bunch of other JDKs. I want to know if there is any difference between OpenJDK 7 and Oracle's JDK 7. Are they basically the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenJDK is the default version of Java that Ubuntu uses and is the easiest to install while Oracle Java 7 is Oracle's own version of Java 7.

You can read [Ubuntu Java Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

OpenJDK: "Oracle makes the OpenJDK source code available under an open-source licensing model. It's both gratis, and free (as in freedom) software."

Further as I found in [Oracle Java FAQ Section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-141681.html#D1)

For Oracle JDK

"The Java Development Kit (JDK) is free to download and use for commercial programming, but not to re-distribute."

Comment: I will use Oracle JDK. Because OpenJDK i have been using several years now, and every day i had nightmares. Since i moved to Oracle JDK all my application problems where solved. That means OpenJDK is bug, to play, to fun, but for Enterprise deploy i will need to always choose Oracle JDK.

Comment: That's an interesting opinion, but could you be more specific ? Have u met problems with threading ? garbage collecting ? And do you think these problems would still be there on openjdk7 and above ?